# Read subfolder python

Tags: python, directory

Im trying to make a data parser but using python for my project but each files are inside a separate folders to each other. Currently i am able to read the first folder but i havent figured out how to read the folder after that and put it in a for loop

```
import os 

r_path='//esw-fs01/esw_niagara_no_bck/BuildResults/master/0.1.52.68_390534/installation_area/autotestlogs_top/'
sd_path='/.'

root = os.listdir(r_path)
subdir=os.listdir(sd_path)
for entry in root:
    # print(entry)
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(r_path, entry)):
        for subentry in subdir:
            if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(r_path,'/ConfigurationsTest_19469')):
                print(subentry)
```

For the second for loop, i want to iterate every folder that are in **autotestlogs** folder. i tried to make it but it doesnt work apparently. Please help Thanks

Comment: Have a look at os.walk, e.g.,  for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(r_path):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you messed your order up a little bit. If you do `subdir = os.listdir(sd_path)` before the loop you can't possibly get the sub directories because you need to use the parent directory to get to them.

So in your loop after you checked that an "entry" is a folder you can store the absolute path of this folder in a variable and then list it's contents with os.listdir().
Then you can loop through those and parse them.

How I would do it:

```
import os

r_path='//esw-fs01/esw_niagara_no_bck/BuildResults/master/0.1.52.68_390534/installation_area/autotestlogs_top/'

root = os.listdir(r_path)

for entry in root:
    # print(entry)
    subdir_path = os.path.join(r_path, entry) #  create the absolute path of the subdir
    if os.path.isdir(subdir_path):  # check if it is a folder
        subdir_entries = os.listdir(subdir_path)  # get the content of the subdir
        for subentry in subdir_entries:
            subentry_path = os.path.join(subdir_path, subentry)  # absolute path of the subentry
            # here you can check everything you want for example if the subentry has a specific name etc
            print(subentry_path)
```

Comment: and i presume if i want to go even deeper i need to make another subdir_entries loop again? thank you btw